# Turning an LR(1) an expression grammar into LL(1)

Tags: compiler, parsing, grammar

I have the following grammar for logical, relational, and arithmetic expressions which I need to make LL(1) compatible.

```
E -> A | B
A -> A op1 T | T
T -> T op2 F | F
F -> ( A ) | v
B -> B lop B2 | B2
B2 -> A rop A | ( B )
op1 -> + | -
op2 -> * | /
rop -> > | < | == | <= | >=
lop -> AND | OR
```

So far I have been able to remove the left recursion

```
E -> A | B
A -> T A2
A2 -> op1 T A2 | e
T -> F T2
T2 -> op2 F T2 | e
F -> ( A ) | v
B -> B2 B3
B3 -> lop B2 B3 | e
B2 -> A rop A | (B)
op1 -> + | -
op2 -> * | /
rop -> > | < | == | <= | >=
lop -> AND | OR
```

Where e is the null string. Now after this I can't figure out how to make it LL(1) compatible.

(This is a homework problem. Any help would be appreciated)

EDIT: My main issue is when an opening parenthesis is encountered at E, with one lookahead I can't decide if the rule

```
E -> A
```

should be followed or the rule

```
E -> B
```

This is because they both derive strings starting with an opening parenthesis. I am not able to figure out how to remove this problem.

Comment: Please add a bit more info about what you tried to solve this and why it didn't work. You know that the current grammar isn't LL(1). That means there are remaining left-recursions or ambiguities. Could you [edit] the question to list these remaining problems? You've already removed left-recursion in some cases, why doesn't your strategy work here?

Comment: All the left recursion and ambiguities have been addressed. The issue is with some kind of left factoring which I am unable to address. Please check the edit above for more details. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about this leads me to believe that the language simply is not LL(1) – remember that the LL languages are just a small fraction of all context free languages. Most current programming languages are LALR. Unfortunately I don't know how to formally prove that your grammar describes a non-LL language.

Answer (score 3):

You have a LR grammar for logical, relational and arithmetic expressions and you'd like an LL(1) grammar for it.

At the lower levels starting with nonterminal `A` or `B` what you have in fact had this correct. It was in thinking you can join them simply with `E -> A | B` is where you went off. And this is simply because you weren't following the pattern that was built up to that point.

In short, instead of a grammar tree that looks like this

```
      E 
   /  |  \
A     B    T
|     |    | \
```

Where A, B, and T are all at the same level (relational, arithmetic, and boolea expressions), instead these items are at different levels in the tree:

```
       E 
     /    \ 
    B      T
  /  |     | 
 A
```

In grammars for expressions such as your example, nonterminals like A, B, T, F add a class of things that you can add to the expression, e.g. for B boolean kinds of expressions; for A arithmetic-relation kinds of expressions.

However the strict hierarchy in the grammar is what specifies operator precedence: that say relational expressions bind more tightly than logical expressions. So when you have `E -> A | B` you violate that hierarchy by having arithmetic and boolean expressions be at the same level and this is what causes the LL(1) grammar to have a "first set" clash: are we trying to predict an arithmetic relational expression or are we trying to predict a logical expression?

So let's break this down back into the part that works, and then let's keep extending that.

You have (using ANTLR syntax):

```
A -> T A2 .
A2 -> op1 T A2 | e .
op1 -> + | - .

T -> F T2 .
T2 -> op2 F T2 | e .
op2 -> * | / .

F -> ( A ) | v .
e -> .
```

And this allows and puts a hierarchy on multiply- versus addition-like expressions. So now let's extend that first to relational arithmetic operators:

```
B -> A B2 .
B2 -> rop A B2 | e .
rop -> > | < | == | <= | >= .

A -> T A2 .
A2 -> op1 T A2 | e .
op1 -> + | - .

T -> F T2 .
T2 -> op2 F T2 | e .
op2 -> * | / .

F -> ( B ) | v .
e -> .
```

And finally to logical operators:

```
E -> B E2 .
E2 -> lop B E2 | e .
lop -> AND | OR .

B -> A B2 .
B2 -> rop A B2 | e .
rop -> > | < | == | <= | >= .

A -> T A2 .
A2 -> op1 T A2 | e .
op1 -> + | - .

T -> F T2 .
T2 -> op2 F T2 | e .
op2 -> * | / .

F -> ( E ) | v .
e -> .
```

Finally, let me say that a google search has turned up this interesting grammar checker: http://mdaines.github.io/grammophone